# Bixby capsules to toggle phone functions?

Tags: android, galaxy, bixby

I can't figure out how to make my bixby function change the state of phone functions. I'd like to toggle the wifi on and off but I can't find how in the documentation.

Are phone features available to bixby capsules?

Answer (score 0):

Bixby already has a build-in capability to switch on/off wifi and many other things you can try with your phone. I've just confirmed that on the S9 device.

Since each device may have different hardware/firmware architecture, and possible security reasons, phone feature is not available in Bixby IDE, except contact list.

You can find more info about viv.contact library in our developer center: 
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.contact

Let us know if it helps, and have fun with Bixby!